# sum the numbers in the second Column according to data in the first column

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language

```
          A                       B                       C
1     Timestamp               Hours Worked            Total Hours
2     1/2/2022 17:33:41       6
3     1/3/2022 19:59:41       2                       January = 
4     1/7/2022 13:20:51       1
5     1/9/2022 12:49:02       3                       February = 
6     1/15/2022 12:04:21      3
7     2/16/2022 15:58:10      9                       March = 
8     2/22/2022 11:57:31      3
9     2/24/2022 5:45:12       5
10    2/2/2022 17:33:41       4
11    2/3/2022 19:59:41       2
12    2/7/2022 13:20:51       1
13    3/9/2022 12:49:02       3
14    3/15/2022 12:04:28      3
15    3/16/2022 15:58:10      7
16    3/22/2022 11:57:31      3
17    3/24/2022 5:45:12       5
```

I would like to sum the hours by date/month. I can sum the hours by
column, =sum(b2:b). But how do I sum the hours in Column B by
date/month of column A?

In another post, a member referenced the 'Google Sheets function list'.
I have found that to be very helpful on other things I have been doing.
But I am still at a lose for this problem.

John

Comment: Can your provide a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: Now it looks a little better.

Comment: I have given a screenshot in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, without any formula, is to build a pivot table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `query` function with SQL:

```
=QUERY({(data)}, "select sum(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'Date', Col2 'Sum'")
```

That would return a new table, and you can adjust it by changing the second parameter, representing the SQL string. You can view Google's docs for the query function [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343). In addition you can find their docs for the query language [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage).

Comment: What happens if I want to select sum() more than one column?

Comment: the you could change the first part to `select sum([col]), sum([col]) ...`. again, I would recommend viewing the docs for the query language or finding documentation for SQL

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(QUERY({TEXT(A2:A, "yyymm\×mmmm"), B2:B}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''")), "(.*×)", ))
```

[image]